# importing Maven Akka project into eclipse

Tags: java, maven, akka

I am trying my hands on the maven java Akka tutorials on the calculation of pi.

Please I am new to both: maven and Akka but want know if it is possible

to create a maven akka project and then import the project into

Eclipse IDE and be able to run  the project in the eclipse IDE.

If it is possible I will be happy for some directions or tutorials

your suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: i have just read the akka tutorials and am yet to try it so want to find any person who has tried it to share their experience with me. but first have to run the java akka pi as a maven project first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/intro/getting-started-first-java.html) You have some  information how start Akka, but first You have to know something about [maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html).

Comment: thanks for the direction. WIll read and try running the akka tutorials and hope after trying the maven in the command prompt then can import the akka into eclipse as an akka maven project

Comment: When You will have a pom.xml (file which contains the project configuration details used by Maven) use command mvn eclipse:eclipse and then You will be able to import project to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Since the exact link in tostao's post does not work anymore here is the link for the latest version of akka:
[Akka Getting Started](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/intro/getting-started.html). Consider replacing *current* in the url with the actual version, 2.9.10 as of writing.

If you use eclipse you might want to have a look into scala-ide.

Typesafe, the company behind Akka and an important part of the scala world, also offer their own build tool i.e. sbt. Especially their typesafe activator templates are build on top of sbt which might suggest a preference of sbt over maven from their part.